# Execute php commands in WAMP environment

Tags: zend-framework, command-line-interface, easyphp

I'm new to working in a WAMP environment, in this case I'm using Easyphp, and I can't find how to execute php commands (like a simple php -v), like I would do for example when connecting to a server with SSH.

I have Easyphp installed, apache and mysql servers are on, and I created a virtual host using the module in the same folder where I'm trying to execute the php command (using the cmd tool in windows).

Is there any other way to do this? Is there a "console" just for that? Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

OK maybe I should give a specific example of what I'm trying to do in case I didn't explain myself very well. I'm trying to follow this [guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) to getting started with Zend Framework, and in the very first step after downloading the files, it asks to "type" 2 commands:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

Where do I exactly "type" those commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows you need to set up your path environment variable (if it hasn't already been done by the installer) so that it points to the correct location for the PHP executables.  Refer to the documentation for EasyPHP to see if/how you need to do this.

Then, open a dos window, and `cd` into the directory for your project. Then you should be able to run the commands as shown.